# How can I update changes in a Table (rhandsontable package) to a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: r, database, shiny, sql-update, crud

I have a very simple shiny App, where I Just display a Table (rhandsontable) with some values. The table is connected to a PostgreSQL database. I just need to know, how can I update the Table to the database. So when I edit the table in the shiny App, I want the database to be updated and when I call the shiny App, it should obviously display the updated values, new rows, etc.
I am very new to programming in general, but I think this should be very simple. I read a bit about "CRUD" and this should be the way to do it, but I have no Idea how to write the code.

```
library(RJDBC)
library(rJava)
library(DBI)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

drv <- JDBC(...)

conn <- dbConnect(drv, host, user, password)

dbListTables(conn)
table = dbReadTable(conn, "db_table")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(rHandsontableOutput("hot")))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
   rhandsontable(table)
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who looked this post up and had the same issue. I solved it using:

```
output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rownames(table) <- NULL
    rhandsontable(table)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    list <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    df <- as.data.frame(list)
    dbWriteTable(conn, name = "startup_db", value = df, overwrite = TRUE)
  })
```